# How to declare a dynamic array inside tuple in CPLEX?

Tags: cplex

I'm declaring an array of tuples in CPLEX. The tuple have a 2D array declared inside them and the length of those arrays would be different for each element of the array of tuples. But the CPLEX is showing errors. I'm attaching the snippet of the code. Can anyone help me with this?

```
int n=...;
range N=1..n;
tuple info{
     int a;
     int b;
     int box[1..b];
     float d;
 }

 info tuplearray[N]=...;
```

Comment: Post the error also

Comment: @Sivabalan in the line "tuple info", it says Invalid Initialization expression for element "info". In the line "int box[1..b]", it says Element "b" not available and in the line info tuplearray[N], it says Invalid Initialization expression for element "tuplearray".

Answer (score 0):

All arrays a in a tuple set have the same size. So I would use tuple sets for that.

Let me give you an example:

.mod

```
int n=4;
range N=1..n;
int m=2;
tuple info{
     int a;
     int b;
     int box[1..m];
     float d;
 }

 info tuplearray[i in N]=...; 
 
 execute
 {
  writeln(tuplearray);
 }
 
 tuple boxitem
 {
 int i;
 int j;
 int v; 
 }
 
 {boxitem} boxitems={<1,1,1>,<2,1,3>,<2,2,4>,<3,1,2>,<4,1,2>};
 int sizes[i in 1..n]=card({t | t in boxitems : t.i==i});
 
 execute
 {
  
 writeln(sizes);
  writeln(boxitems);
 }
```

.dat

```
tuplearray=[<1,2,[1,2],1.5>,<3,4,[3,2],1.5>,<1,2,[4,2],1.5>,<7,8,[6,2],1.5>,];
```

Comment: Thanks @alexfleischer for the answer. But this is not what i'm looking for. I want to declare dynamic arrays inside the tuple the length of which will be different for each element of array of tuples. So let's say if I have declared "info tuplearray [1..2]", the i want "tuplearray[1].box" to be of length, let's say 3, and "tuplearray[2].box" to be of length 4. Is it possible in CPLEX? And if it's not, Is there any other way i can go about doing this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That s not possible and this is why I gave you a workaround. Other workaround but ugly you use size maxsize and you have a field real size in the tuple